# Better development with Maven

Tags: maven, maven-2

I'm managing my web app using Maven. Maven copies all to the target folder beside src.

Con: You need to run the package task on each little change in a jsp to see the changes.

There's no better way I guess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use eclipse with the m2 plugin.  When running your webapp from within eclipse it auto publishes the changes to the running container.

Comment: How did you configured the plugin? And how does it starts the running Container (in my case Tomcat7)?

Comment: I've installed m2e, m2e-wtp. Tomcat7 Server is already configured. Building the war works great. Starting the Server as well, but I'm just getting a 404 and it seems the Server doesn't know of that webapp...

Comment: You have to add your webapp to tomcat in the server tab in eclipse.  Right click on Tomcat and choose 'And and Remove...'

Answer (score 0):

You can use a web container started by Maven such as the Eclipse Jetty Plugin, or the Glassfish plugin (for example) and you can set scan intervals and the changes to web resources will get picked up.